# Is it possible to displace an Array on Java?

Tags: java, android, arrays

Developing an application for Android, i want to record data that will be usefull only for some seconds, so I've thought to use an array that is everytime displacing to the right.Something like:

```
i>i+1, i+1>i+2, i+2>i+3 ...
```

Is it possible to do this directly, or Do I have to use a `for` in order to move all data on the array every time I want to add info?

Comment: Use a more appropriate data structure.

Comment: Because, as I have designed it, I need to see like a "temporal progression" and I'd like to compare the samples. But I'll think about this. Maybe changing my algorithm so it fully overrides samples works too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you thought about using a stack? I'm not sure if there is something like that in Android SDK but you asked for Java :) http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html

Comment: Usually Android uses the same classes as Java:
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Stack.html

Comment: Wow, I didn't know about Stacks. I'm going to study them! (And yes, you can use stacks on Android either :) )

Answer (score 1):

You can use a queue for that:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html

Comment: In terms of representation, this seems more like a stack

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with the data, you could also use just a normal List.

Comment: I think a queue might be the right way to it too but I don't think a List can be :). The advantage of the stack is, that you can set a maximum size and do not have to care about popping old entries off the end.

Comment: You can use the normal list.add(...) method to instert new elements and list.get(list.size()-1) to get the most recent element

Comment: Care about complexity. In stack returning last inserted element has O(1) complexity

Answer (score 0):

Although you can either implement this using for loop or use `System.arraycopy(src, srcPos, dest, destPos, length)` call I'd recommend you to use one of available collections. Better java.util.List. For your use case LinkedList is probably the best choice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Stack](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) and every time when you need observe last inserted element use `Stack.peek()`